# Best method to traverse into each element and perform action via jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to figure out how to traverse into elements depending on a class name and perform some action if it has this class or do something else if it doesn't.

Please see my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var container = $('.container');

     container.each(function() {
          // if all list item has class of hidden then hide parent container
          container.hide();

          // if not all list item has class of hidden then show parent container
          container.show();
     });
});
</script>

<div class="container container1">
     <ul>
          <li class="item">item 1</li>
          <li class="item hidden">item 2</li>
          <li class="item">item 3</li>
          <li class="item">item 4</li>
     </ul>
</div>

<div class="container container2">
     <ul>
          <li class="item hidden">item 1</li>
          <li class="item hidden">item 2</li>
          <li class="item hidden">item 3</li>
          <li class="item hidden">item 4</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

From the code above the desired result is container2 should be completely hidden because all the list item within has a class of "hidden".  While container1 shows because not all list items have the class "hidden".

As you can see, I got as far as using the "each" function to iterate through the containers but I am stuck on how to implement where it will check each list item for the specific class.  My thought would be to perform another each function within it? But not sure...

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Why do you need to perform the second one ("*if not all list item has class of hidden then show parent container*")?

Comment: Oh because this is actually a function that gets called as a callback so if it hides it, it also needs to show it if criteria is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further select with `container` as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) and hide the container, when the number of hidden items is equal to all list items. Show otherwise.

```
$('.container').each(function() {
  var li1 = $('li', $(this)).length;
  var li2 = $('li.hidden', $(this)).length;
  if (li1 == li2)
    $(this).hide();
  else
    $(this).show();
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rGnL/1/) for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Playing code golf:

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(!!$('li:not(.hidden)',this).length);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Ajjkc/

Comment: this seems to work however when it is called again, the containers do not show...Another words, it hides it correctly but calling it a second time does not make the container appear again.  could this be because once the container is hidden, the "each" function cannot see it? If so, how to remedy that?  Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

```
container.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.find('li:not(.hidden)').length ) {
        $this.show();
    } else {
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5AHQZ/

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is something like this is you loop:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var container = $('.container > ul > li');

     container.each(function(index, element) {
          if($(element).hasClass('hidden')){
            $(element).css({display: 'none'});
          }
     });
});
```

I modified the selector too.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.item.hidden').length == $(this).find('.item').length)
        $(this).hide();
    else
        $(this).show();        
});
```